Integration by parts on an area



I'm reading an Engineering book. All I can think of is integration by parts
$$\int_{\Omega} \dfrac{\partial M_y}{\partial x}v\text{d}\Omega = M_y v|_{?}^{?} - \int_{\Omega} M_y\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\text{d}\Omega$$ and use the boundary condition(v=0 on $\Gamma$) to get the equation (38), but Ive only learnt integration by parts in the one-dimensional situation, I don't know how to handle this $\Omega$ area situation.

I've come up with an idea.
$$
\begin{align*}
& \int_\Omega \dfrac{\partial M_y}{\partial x}v\text{d}\Omega\\
=& \int_y\int_{x(y)} \dfrac{\partial M_y}{\partial x}v\text{d}x\text{d}y\\
=& \int_y(M_y v|_{x(y)}-\int_{x(y)}M_y\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx)dy\\
=& -\int_y\int_{x(y)}M_y\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}dxdy\ (\text{Using the boundary condition})\\
=& -\int_\Omega M_y\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}d\Omega
\end{align*}
$$
Similarly $$-\int_\Omega \dfrac{\partial M_x}{\partial y}v\text{d}\Omega = \int_\Omega M_x\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}d\Omega$$
If the boundary condition is not given, I have to deal with the integration like $\int_y M_y v|_{x(y)}dy$ and it's not the most beautiful form though.

This is not really mathematically correct. How exactly do you write $\int_\Omega = \int_y \int_{x(y)}$? And what kind of "integration by parts" do you use to get $\int_{x(y)} \frac{\partial M_y}{\partial x}v,dx = M_y v\vert_{x(y)} - \int_{x(y)} M_y\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},dx$? As seen in the answer by Noctis, you have to use the multidimensional generalisation of integration by parts.

There is an multi dimensional formula for partial integration:
$$\int_\Omega \varphi\, \operatorname{div}\,  \vec v  \; \mathrm d V = \oint_{\partial \Omega} \varphi\, \vec v \cdot \mathrm d \vec S - \int_\Omega  \vec v\cdot \operatorname{grad}\, \varphi  \; \mathrm dV$$
You can find more about it in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts.
